# JavaScript to translate date formats

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have a piece of js that will automatically translate a given date format to different date formats.

In my Database I have all dates formatted as such: ex. 1941-10-30 08:00:00

I would like the code to pick the dates out of that string and convert them to 30.10.1941 and separate the time stamp.

Can I get some pointers to get me going? I am a relatively new coder with js

Thanks in advance

Comment: use moementjs https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), it is very simple and useful for any operations regarding timestamps.

just you can use `moment('YOUR_TIME_STAMP').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)`

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at its `parse` (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) and `format` (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) functions

Comment: moment.js is / was a great package, bt it has been superseded by HTML5 and javascript improvements. Their site explains it is going to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

this is normal date format returned by `new Date()` `2002-12-09T00:00:00.000Z`

and to convert it to only `MM/DD/YYYY` you can do:

```
const date = new Date("2002-12-09T00:00:00.000Z").toLocaleDateString();
```

and to convert it to time:

```
const date = new Date("2002-12-09T00:00:00.000Z").toLocaleTimeString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input format won't change and you want a very simple solution with no external libraries, you can do the following:

```
yourDate = new Date('1941-10-30 08:00:00');  // Convert to JS Date

// Method 1
formattedDateString = yourDate.getDate()+'.'+(yourDate.getMonth()+1)+'.'+yourDate.getFullYear();  // Format to the desired date format, Method 1

// Method 2 
formattedDateString2 = yourDate.toLocaleString('en-gb', { day: '2-digit', month: 'numeric',year: 'numeric' });
formattedDateString2 = formattedDateString2.replace(/\//g, '.'); // remove space and comma

// See the output
console.log(formattedDateString); // Method 1
console.log(formattedDateString2); // Method 2
```

Comment: How would it look if I wanted a date format like 30 Oct 1941?

Comment: @Woop You can use something like this: `yourDate.toLocaleString('default', { day: '2-digit'}) + ' ' + adate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short'}) + ' ' + adate.toLocaleString('default', { year: 'numeric' });`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your time string like that:

```js
const str = `1941-10-30 08:00:00`;
const [y, m, d] = str.split(/[ -]+/);
const [h, mi, s] = str.split(/[ ]+/)[1].split(/[:]+/);

const mydate = new Date(y, m, d, null,  h, mi, s);
const formattedDate = `${d}.${m}.${y}`;

console.log(`my date: `, formattedDate);
console.log(mydate.toTimeString());
```

Try to avoid using `Date` contructors and `Date.parse()` methods as [some incorrect parsing results can be given.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with when I needed to convert *mm/dd/yyyy* to verity of different formats. e.g *dd/mm/yyyy*, *yyyy/mm/dd*, *yyyy-mm-dd*, *dd.mm.yyyy* (it typescript, though just remove type hinting and you'll get vanilla js)

```
const dateStringToFormat = (dateString: string, format: string): string => {
    const parts = dateString.split('/'); // assume incoming date format is mm/dd/yyyy
    const date = new Date(Date.UTC(+parts[2], +parts[0]-1, +parts[1]));
    let delimiter = '.';
    if (format.includes('/')) {
        delimiter = '/'
    } else if (format.includes('-')) {
        delimiter = '-';
    }

    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = (date.getMonth() + 1 + '').padStart(2, '0');
    const day = (date.getDate() + '').padStart(2, '0');
    const position = (idx:number) => idx === 0 ? 0 : (idx < 6 ? 1 : 2);

    const partsForamtted = [];
    partsForamtted[position(format.indexOf('yyyy'))] = year;
    partsForamtted[position(format.indexOf('mm'))] = month;
    partsForamtted[position(format.indexOf('dd'))] = day;

    return partsForamtted.join(delimiter);
}
```

Use like this:

```
dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') //24-03-2021
```

And here is unit tests for the function:

```
describe('test dateStringToFormat function', () => {
  // incoming format is mm/dd/yyyy
  test('Test formats with different delimeters, month followed by date and by year', () => {
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy')).toBe('03/24/2021');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'mm.dd.yyyy')).toBe('03.24.2021');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy')).toBe('03-24-2021');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('12/05/2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy')).toBe('12-05-2021');
  })
  test('Test formats with different delimeters, year followed by month and by date', () => {
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'yyyy/mm/dd')).toBe('2021/03/24');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'yyyy.mm.dd')).toBe('2021.03.24');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'yyyy-mm-dd')).toBe('2021-03-24');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('12/05/2021', 'yyyy-mm-dd')).toBe('2021-12-05');
  })
  test('Test formats with different delimeters, date followed by month and by year', () => {
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')).toBe('24/03/2021');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy')).toBe('24.03.2021');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('03/24/2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy')).toBe('24-03-2021');
    expect(dateStringToFormat('12/05/2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy')).toBe('05-12-2021');
  })
})
```